# Difference between runScrip and storeEval commands

Tags: selenium-ide, run-script

I am a beginner in testing. I am doing my internship on testing and trying to learn about all the commands in selenium IDE. I would really appreciate if someone could help me. I want to know the difference between runScript and storeEval commands. I understand the basic difference by the reference but i want to know in detail. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do:

```
runScript | somethingwrong
storeEval | if (1==1) 'lol' //Or any valid js | somevar
echo      | ${somevar}
echo      | javascript{if (storedVars['somevar'] != 'lol') {'???';} else {'We can do js here too'}}
storeEval | somethingwrong                    | somevar
getEval   | somethingwrong
verifyEval| storedVars['somevar'] == 'lol'    | true
verifyEval| {if (1==1) true}                  | false
```

And run each line with doubleclick one by one.

**runScript**

It's returning nothing. And it is not wrapped by selenium IDE. It means that wrong script will not cause any error in selenium IDE. **But** it will cause js error in the browser. It may be useful if you want to use browser debugging tools to treat some js error

**storeEval**

It is storing result of a javascript to a variable. And it is wrapped by Selenium IDE it means that broken script will cause error right in the Selenium IDE and test will be stopped in that case. You will be able read error right in the Selenium IDE log.

**echo**

Can run javascript too. But please do it for debugging only. If your js is broken it will hang the test.

**getEval**

It's returning no result. Everything else like in storeEval. Broken js will fail the test.

**verifyEval**

Is for verifying variables. It will fail the test in case if two evals provided are not equal. You can use to run javascript too. It is very useful when you need not only get the result of javascript but fail the test if your the result is not acceptable.

So:

**runScript** is to just do script and go further (maybe with errors in browser console)

**getEval** is to run script and fail in case of something wrong

**storeEval** is to run script and retrieve the result to use it later

**verifyEval** is to run script and verify the result.

**echo** is not for running scripts. But you can do it. For debugging only.

There are a number of other ways to run script using Selenium IDE. But it's already a lot.

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thank you so much @Antesser. It is very helpful.